# How do I get the google drive location?

Tags: google-drive-api

How can I programmatically get (possibly without using the SDK) the location where the google drive in installed.

I just need the name of the root directory so that I can open it inside my windows application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this code to extract the information I need.
I'm posting it in case someone can benefit from it.
I use SQLite to extract the information from the sync_config.db file.

```
String dbFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Google\\Drive\\sync_config.db");

string csGdrive = @"Data Source=" + dbFilePath + ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;";

        try {
            using (var con = new SQLiteConnection(csGdrive)) {
                con.Open();
                using (var sqLitecmd = new SQLiteCommand(con)) {
                    //To retrieve the folder use the following command text
                    sqLitecmd.CommandText = "select * from data where entry_key='local_sync_root_path'";

                    using (var reader = sqLitecmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                        reader.Read();
                        //String retrieved is in the format "\\?\<path>" that's why I have used Substring function to extract the path alone.
                        destFolder = reader["data_value"].ToString().Substring(4);
                        Console.WriteLine("Google Drive Folder: " + destFolder);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are talking about the Google Drive installed app for [Windows and Mac](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive).

There is no API to determine where the user placed their drive folder on the local machine as that is specific to the local machine and not the user's Google account.

On Windows, the Drive app store's the local Drive path in a SQLite 3 database located at:

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Drive\sync_config.db`

It's safe to assume the Mac app uses a similarly named SQLite database file located in the user's home directory.

Comment: On my machine the folder is `C:\Users\p620327\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\user_default`. Maybe it was changed by Google at some point.

Answer (score 1):

A simple python script

```
import sqlite3
import os

# Get Google Drive path

db_path = (os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA')+'\\Google\\Drive\\user_default\\sync_config.db')      
db = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * from data where entry_key = 'local_sync_root_path'")
res = cursor.fetchone()
path = res[2][4:]
db.close()

print(path)
```